# Copy data from one tab in browser and paster into another

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, copy-paste

I need to copy text from one tab and paste to another on click. They are in the same browser but domains are different so they don't share same origins.

Possible solutions I've considered: setup a web worker, do it using a socket or even custom chrome extension. The main goal is to perform this operation when user clicks on a button, then data automatically gets copied to another tab.

Comment: Thankfully, it's impossible. Well, technically, a browser extension could work, but it will never get approved anywhere.

Comment: Does window receiving message have message or drop event listeners?

Comment: check [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) - cross domain messaging

Comment: Is tab opened from first window?

Comment: did you try sessionstorage?

Comment: There are security issues with that. Evil websites could grab content from users other tabs and windows. Fortunately modern browsers protect against such evilness. See [MDN Web Security - Same Origin Policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Yes, tab is opened from a first window. I know that it is not possible if websites have different domain, but thought there might be a "hack" besides developing an extension.